# Stopping newly created child div form interferring with original mouseover/hover

Tags: jquery

I've appended popup text into a div. Its text is sometimes larger than the parent div and mouseleave only gets triggered if you've also left all of the added text (not just the rectangle - which is how I'd like it to work)

http://jsfiddle.net/h4vvk/1/

In that link, when you hover over the rectangle red text appears. Usually you can stop the hover by getting out of the current div but in this case sometimes the popup text is bigger than the rectangle and hover doesn't end unless you get off of the text as well as the div rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css `pointer-events` property:

```
.hover-text {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h4vvk/4/

Comment: it is not cross-browser-compatible though